# Error while passing string in Network Programming in C

Tags: c, network-programming

I am implementing an HTTP server from scratch in C where I read a config file to get the path of the required file. But, when I read the file and pass it's value as a string to the function, I don't get `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` error.

Attaching a few snippets of my code-

```
char index_loc[20];
char const* const fileName = "config.txt";
    FILE* file = fopen(fileName, "r");
    if(!file){
        printf("\n Unable to open : %s ", fileName);
        return -1;
    }
fgets(index_loc, sizeof(index_loc), file);
setHttpHeader(httpHeader, index_loc);
```

The function,  `void setHttpHeader(char httpHeader[], char page[])` is working completely fine when I pass  `setHttpHeader(httpHeader, "index.html");` to it.

Config file:-

```
8080
index.html
```

The port number is being read correctly from the file.

Comment: if you're programming `C`, you need to use a debugger like `gdb`.  There's simply no other effective way to debug things like segmentation faults.  But, one thing I do notice in your code, you have `index_loc` but also `about_loc` and you don't include code doing anything else with `about_loc`.  You really must include a minimal, verifiable example of your code for meaningful advise.  Sound like your question doesn't involve any network programming really.  You want to open a file whose path is in a string, and read 20 bytes.  Write a complete, minimal example that does that and only that.

Comment: "The port number is being read correctly from the file." That code does not read it at all. With the given example you are passing string `"8080\n"` to your function, not `"index.html"`. Even if you read the port in your real code, you must be aware that `fgets` will include the `\n` into the string.